# API request does not work on GCP VM with Mega-ai

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, virtual-machine

I am trying to fetch the data from NBP API (Polish National Bank API) with application created in Mage-ai. Mage-ai is set up on GCP VM.Please find the code below.

```
import requests
from datetime import date
from dateutil.relativedelta import relativedelta


if 'data_loader' not in globals():
    from mage_ai.data_preparation.decorators import data_loader
if 'test' not in globals():
    from mage_ai.data_preparation.decorators import test


@data_loader
def load_data_from_api(*args, **kwargs):
    """
    Template for loading data from API
    """
    
    #start date for NBP data limited by NBP API
    nbp_start_date = (date.today() - relativedelta(years = 1)).strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
    end_date = date.today().strftime('%Y-%m-%d')

    url = f"https://api.nbp.pl/api/cenyzlota/{nbp_start_date}/{end_date}"
    
    response = requests.get(url)
    
    if response.status_code == 200:
        nbp_exchange_rates = response.json()
    elif response.status_code == 404:
        print(f'Error: Failed to fetch data. Status code: {response.status_code} Not Found')
    elif response.status_code == 400:
        print(f'Error: Failed to fetch data. Status code: {response.status_code} Bad Request')
        
    return nbp_exchange_rates


@test
def test_output(output, *args) -> None:
    """
    Template code for testing the output of the block.
    """
    assert output is not None, 'The output is undefined'
```

I would appreciate any suggestion.

When I am running the code in Data loader block it returns the data only from 1 day.
When I am running the same code in Scratchpad block it works properly.
When I am running the code on my local PC, it works properly.

What's more, I have 2nd API request with the same code structure and differenty URL form NBP API, this one works properly in Data loader block. Code for the 2nd request below:

```
import requests
from datetime import date
from dateutil.relativedelta import relativedelta


if 'data_loader' not in globals():
    from mage_ai.data_preparation.decorators import data_loader
if 'test' not in globals():
    from mage_ai.data_preparation.decorators import test


@data_loader
def load_data_from_api(*args, **kwargs):
    """
    Template for loading data from API
    """
    
    #start date for NBP data limited by NBP API
    nbp_start_date = (date.today() - relativedelta(years = 1)).strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
    end_date = date.today().strftime('%Y-%m-%d')

    currency_code = 'USD'
    url = f"https://api.nbp.pl/api/exchangerates/rates/a/{currency_code}/{nbp_start_date}/{end_date}"
    
    response = requests.get(url)
    
    if response.status_code == 200:
        nbp_exchange_rates = response.json()
    elif response.status_code == 404:
        print(f'Error: Failed to fetch data. Status code: {response.status_code} Not Found')
    elif response.status_code == 400:
        print(f'Error: Failed to fetch data. Status code: {response.status_code} Bad Request')
        
    return nbp_exchange_rates


@test
def test_output(output, *args) -> None:
    """
    Template code for testing the output of the block.
    """
    assert output is not None, 'The output is undefined'
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems like there could be an issue with the API endpoint with the first request or there might be some settings that don't meet the requirement of Mage-ai. You might want to check the endpoint parameters are correct and verify that the URL is formatted as expected and that the date range is appropriate. Also use a more detailed logging to understand where the code might be failing so that troubleshooting would be easier. Attached is Mage-AI documentation to help you troubleshoot further.[1]

[1] https://docs.mage.ai/development/troubleshooting